# On vs In In the given sentence

Tags: prepositions

Which one of the following is correct?

***On the pulpit/In the pulpit.***

I *Hope* it is **on** the pulpit.

Comment: Please provide a complete sentence. The exact construction will change the preposition.

Answer (score 2):

"On the pulpit" is better.

Mostly when you want to express that something is on a surface or top - use "On"!

Comment: Which One Is Correct?

Giving birth **on / in** the street .

Comment: On is the best one to use